# Is it possible to render over the tab bar?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Simple question, the way the library seems to be built it seems like I can't render anything directly over the tab bar correct?

I was trying to use z-indexing and elevation, but dosen't appear to be working..

Answer (score 0):

Which version of RNN are you using?
I am using RNN v1 and I am too using a tab bar. Whenever I have pushed a new screen from the screen with the tabs, I am hiding the tab bar like this in the new screen:

static navigatorStyle = {
    tabBarHidden: true
  }

Hope it helps!